# How can I hide all the idle processes in htop?

Tags: top, htop

`top` hides all the idle processes with the `-i` flag. From `man` of the `top`:

```bsh
PERFORMANCE/ACCURACY TRADEOFF
   Calculating detailed memory statistics is fundamentally resource-intensive.  
   To reduce the CPU usage in top, the -i option has been introduced to
   allow the user to tune this tradeoff.  With the default value of 10, 
   framework stats will be updated once every 10 samples. Specifying -i 1 will
   result in the most accurate display, at the expense of system resources.
```

[Q] Would it be possible to apply similar approach in `htop`?

Comment: You're misinterpreting the `man` page for `top`. The "`-i`" you quoted is a command line option. The "`i`" to suppress idle tasks isn't the same as "`-i`". Read `man htop top`.

Comment: @waltinator you are right I removed the `-i` command line section